# Python | Appengine: What is the bug in my code that is preventing me from getting output as "Welcome, (username of the person)"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Definitely a beginner question. I'm trying to get the output as 'Welcome, (username of the person)' (say, Welcome, John). But I'm getting the output as just 'Welcome, '.
Any help would be highly appreciable.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db
import os
import jinja2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                           autoescape = True)

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(render_str(template, **kw))

    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)



class Name(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required=True)


class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('input.html')
    def post(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        a = Name(username=username)
        a.put()

        self.redirect('/welcome')


class WelcomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')

        self.render('welcome.html', username = username)



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainHandler),
  ('/welcome',WelcomeHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your welcome handler never actually tries to pull data from the datastore ... It's getting the username from the *request* -- If you're getting there via the redirect, it would be something like `self.redirect('/welcome?username=...')`.

Of course, this isn't *actually* what you're trying to do.  Generally, you'll want to attach some sort of handle on the datastore entry that you can use to pull it back out later.  In this case, you might want to use the [`users`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) service:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb  # Note, I'm using ndb rather than db

class Name(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('input.html')
    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        username = self.request.get('username')
        a = Name(id=user.id(), username=username)
        a.put()

        self.redirect('/welcome')

class WelcomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        key = ndb.key(user.id())
        name_entity = key.get()
        self.render('welcome.html', username=name_entity.username)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at in the last para: gets by key are always guaranteed to be consistent.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- Are they?  That's good to know.  I never understood the whole "storing for strong consistency" bit.  :)  I'll strike through that comment for now while I research it a bit more.  Hopefully I'll remember to come back and resolve it later...

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- Ahh ... I think I believe you now -- If I understand correctly, an entity is in it's own entity group, so accessing it directly is always strongly consistent.

Comment: Any get by key is consistent, because you are not accessing via an index. Whether it has an ancestor or not is not really relevant, thoush as you say a fully specified key always includes any ancestors.

Comment: @TimHoffman -- So you're saying that "inconsistencies" arise due to the "slowness" of _indexing_ the entity, not _replicating_ the entity to other data centers and the possibility that subsequent requests may not be handled in the same data center?  Learning a lot here -- Glad I answered this question :-)

Comment: There can be problems replicating to datacentres we have seen this, but in that situation there is nothing you can do, as it is an infrastructure outage.